# access blob value outside of canvas.ToBlob() async function

Tags: javascript, html, promise

I'm working with `HTMLCanvas` element that return the blob object outside of the `async toBlob()` function. This function doesn't return an output value, so I'm trying to declare a variable outside and access it through the command.

**How I can use `JS Promise` for this scenario?**

```html
var myblob;
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {                         
                              myblob = blob;
                              console.log("inside " + myblob); // getting value after the console outside
                           })
 console.log( "outside " + myblob); // getting undefined
```

Comment: Perform the task within `.toBlob()` callback or use `Promise` constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Promise` constructor, pass `Blob` instance to `resolve()`, access `Promise` value at `.then()`

```
function getCanvasBlob(canvas) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      resolve(blob)
    })
  })
}

var canvasBlob = getCanvasBlob(canvas);

canvasBlob.then(function(blob) {
  // do stuff with blob
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much and apreciate your prompt response. My issue, is I have to set the value of blob in a global variable so that I can access it outside the this function. eg: inside the canvasBlob.then(function(blob)){ this.something = blob; }

Comment: You will not be able to access `Blob` until `.toBlob()` callback returns a value.  Use first function passed to `.then()` to perform task with `Blob` from `.toBlob()` callback.

Comment: Thanks. In my scenario, I have a video element and canvas to capture a snapshot from the video and render it in an image control. Currently the code executes in the capturing mouse click event. Now, once I have the picture I have to let the user to click on a button send that picture to the server via ajax request. Currently toBlob() is executing in the capture event, i would like to see if there is way to get that blob stored so that i can access it in the button click event to submit it to the server. Any advise would be very helpful !

Comment: I think by calling the .toblob() second time in the button click returns the same image. Thank you !

Comment: Your initial attempt is close. When `.toBlob()` is called, assign `myblob` the value of `Blob` at `.toBlob()` callback. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234835/how-to-take-a-photo-of-an-img-video-stream-html5-javascript/

Answer (score 74):

```js
const blob = await new Promise(resolve => canvasElem.toBlob(resolve));
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: Bralliant indeed :)

Comment: Awesome! Could you, or anyone, explain it?

Comment: toBlob(resolve); // would be like toBlob(blob => resolve(blob));

Answer (score 4):

Typescript version:

```js
function toBlob(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob(blob => {
      if (blob) resolve(blob);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I HAVE ANOTHER IDEA... similar to the one marked as best idea... the problem with **then** is that you have to be inside the block in order to pick up the result from the promise.  Now Javascript supports **await** similar to c#, this is good because you can run the function and wait until is resolved, then you get the result to a variable not attached to any function, example:

```js
/* basically we create a function that receives a canvas called mycanvas, then we tell the function to return a new Promise, this promise is "resolved" inside the .toBlob method which by default provides a Blob parameter. */

function getCanvasBlob(mycanvas) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mycanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      resolve(blob)
    })
  })
}

var myblob;

try{
  myblob = await getCanvasBlob(CANVAS_FROM_SOMEWHERE);
}
catch (error){
  console.log(error);
}

/* There's no need to use try/catch, you could use it just like this */

var myblob = await getCanvasBlob(CANVAS_FROM_SOMEWHERE);
```

As the method is async, **then()** is not executed or called until the promise is resolved, anything outside this method will not be notified of changes until is too late... The advantage here is that our javascript will not continue until the promise has been fully resolved.

ADDITIONAL INFO: If you call await, the method from where you are calling this function must be marked as async, otherwise you will see an error... lets say for example this is called inside a click of a button:

```js
/* OBVIOUSLY this will throw an error because I don't have a real canvas...*/

$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $('#mybutton').bind('click', async function(){
    
      //...more code...
      //...more code... until...
      
      var CANVAS_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
      
      var myblob = await getCanvasBlob(CANVAS_FROM_SOMEWHERE);
    
    });
    
});

function getCanvasBlob(mycanvas) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mycanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      resolve(blob)
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">process my canvas!</button>
```