# How to store large files to web local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, caching, local-storage

I am developing ionic 2 app that downloads files from online servers, I want to store those files to the local storage (or caches I don't know).

I know that I can store data to local storage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

But if it is file and specially a large one, how to store it in local storage?

Note: I am using TypeScript.

Answer (score 29):

### For your consideration in 2022: *Origin Private File System*

As of early-2022 IndexedDB remains the best overall choice for persisting binary data (e.g. images and videos, user files from `<input type="file">`, JS `File` and `Blob` objects, etc) due to its support for both asynchronous IO and ability to save raw binary data without needing ugly hacks like Base64-encoding for `data:` URIs.

However, IndexedDB has probably one of the least well-designed API surfaces in HTML5 (<sub>"you wire-up event-handlers *after* you trigger the event? crazy!</sub>), and the browser-vendors agree: so Apple's Safari and Google's Chromium both now support a simpler data persistence API named **Origin Private File System** (OPFS) which was recently introduced in 2021.

- [Google Chrome supports it since Chrome 102](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5702777582911488).
- [Apple Safari supports it since](https://webkit.org/blog/12257/the-file-system-access-api-with-origin-private-file-system/) macOS 12.2+ and iOS 15.2+.
- As of October 2022, [Mozilla Firefox should be supporting it soon](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1748667) <sub>([Earlier on Mozilla's devs had reservations](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/562), [but it looks like they're pressing ahead with it](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/562#issuecomment-1109504819), phew!</sub>.

---

- OPFS is a subset of [the larger WHATWG File System API](https://whatpr.org/fs/1.html) and is also related to the [extant WHATWG Storage API](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/) (which defines `localStorage`, `indexedDB`, etc).
- Despite OPFS's name containing the term "File System", OPFS **does not involve any access to the user's actual local computer file-system**: think of it more as an isolated *virtual* or "pretend" file-system that's scoped to a single website (specifically, scoped to a single origin), so different websites/origins cannot access other websites' OPFS storage.
- OPFS lacks an initial fixed-size storage quota, whereas `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` both [have an initial limit of 5MB](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#storage-endpoint-quota).

  - However this is not an invitation to store gigabytes of junk on users' computers in OPFS: browsers impose their own soft limits, and if you hit the limit your write operations to OPFS will throw `QuotaExceededError` which you should be prepared to handle gracefully.
- Because OPFS doesn't involve the user's actual local filesystem, and because the space is segregated by [origin (URI-scheme + hostname + port)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), it means that OPFS doesn't present a risk of users' privacy  or computer security, so browsers won't interrupt your script to show your users a potentially scary-looking security-prompt that the user has to click-through to explicitly grant or deny your website or page's ability to use the OPFS API.

  - Though browsers *could* still add such a prompt in future if they choose, and of course, browsers can always just disable OPFS and reject all attempts to use it, just as with `indexedDB` and `localStorage` today, or even *pretend* to persist data between page-loads or sessions (e.g. as in Chrome's Incognito mode).

---

#### Using OPFS:

[Apple have detailed usage examples in the WebKit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/12257/the-file-system-access-api-with-origin-private-file-system/).

As a brief introduction: you use OPFS via `navigator.storage` and awaiting `getDirectory()` to get a `FileSystemHandle` object representing the root directory of your website (origin)'s storage space, and then await methods on the root to create and manipulate files and subdirectories.

For example, supposing you have a `<canvas>` element with some *oh-so fantastic* original art your user painted by hand and wants to save locally as a PNG blob in the browser's OPFS storage space, then you'd do something like this:

```js
async function doOpfsDemo() {

    // Open the "root" of the website's (origin's) private filesystem:
    let storageRoot = null;
    try {
        storageRoot = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( err );
        alert( "Couldn't open OPFS. See browser console.\n\n" + err );
        return;
    }

    // Get the <canvas> element from the page DOM:
    const canvasElem = document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' );

    // Save the image:
    await saveCanvasToPngInOriginPrivateFileSystem( storageRoot, canvasElem );

    // (Re-)load the image:
    await loadPngFromOriginPrivateFileSystemIntoCanvas( storageRoot, canvasElem );
}

async function saveCanvasToPngInOriginPrivateFileSystem( storageRoot, canvasElem ) {

    // Save the <canvas>'s image to a PNG file to an in-memory Blob object: (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942679/159145 ):
    const imagePngBlob = await new Promise(resolve => canvasElem.toBlob( resolve, 'image/png' ) );

    // Create an empty (zero-byte) file in a new subdirectory: "art/mywaifu.png":
    const newSubDir = await storageRoot.getDirectoryHandle( "art", { "create" : true });
    const newFile   = await newSubDir.getFileHandle( "mywaifu.png", { "create" : true });

    // Open the `mywaifu.png` file as a writable stream ( FileSystemWritableFileStream ):
    const wtr = await newFile.createWritable();
    try {
        // Then write the Blob object directly:
        await wtr.write( imagePngBlob );
    }
    finally {
        // And safely close the file stream writer:
        await wtr.close();
    }
}

async function loadPngFromOriginPrivateFileSystemIntoCanvas( storageRoot, canvasElem ) {
    
    const artSubDir = await storageRoot.getDirectoryHandle( "art" );
    const savedFile = await artSubDir.getFileHandle( "mywaifu.png" ); // Surprisingly there isn't a "fileExists()" function: instead you need to iterate over all files, which is odd... https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/
    
    // Get the `savedFile` as a DOM `File` object (as opposed to a `FileSystemFileHandle` object):
    const pngFile = await savedFile.getFile();
    
    // Load it into an ImageBitmap object which can be painted directly onto the <canvas>. You don't need to use URL.createObjectURL and <img/> anymore. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap
    // But you *do* still need to `.close()` the ImageBitmap after it's painted otherwise you'll leak memory. Use a try/finally block for that.
    try {
        const loadedBitmap = await createImageBitmap( pngFile ); // `createImageBitmap()` is a global free-function, like `parseInt()`. Which is unusual as most modern JS APIs are designed to not pollute the global scope.
        try {
            const ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect( /*x:*/ 0, /*y:*/ 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height ); // Clear the canvas before drawing the loaded image.
            ctx.drawImage( loadedBitmap, /*x:*/ 0, /*y:*/ 0 ); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
        }
        finally {
            loadedBitmap.close(); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap/close
        }
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( err );
        alert( "Couldn't load previously saved image into <canvas>. See browser console.\n\n" + err );
        return;
    }
}
```

---

- Remember that OPFS filesystem spaces are not representative of their underlying filesystem, *if any*, on the user's computer: an extant `FileSystemFileHandle` in an OPFS space will not necessarily exist in the user's real file-system.

  - In fact, it's more likely they'll be physically persisted the same way as IndexedDB blobs are: as a range of bytes nested inside some other data-store file, e.g. Chromium-based browsers use their own database-engine named [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) while Safari [seems to use a journaled Sqlite DB](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202137) for their IndexedDB backing-store. You can see them yourself: On Windows, Chrome/Chromium/Edge stores LevelDB database files for IndexedDB at `C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB`.
- OPFS is also very simple: while your computer's NTFS, ZFS, or APFS file-system will have features like permissions/ACLs, ownership, low-level (i.e. block-level) access, snapshotting and history, and more, OPFS lacks all of those: OPFS doesn't even have a file-locking mechanism, which is usually considered an essential primitive FS operation.

  - Obviously this keeps OPFS's API surface simpler: making it easier to implement and easier to use than otherwise, not to mention shrinking the potential attack surface, but it does mean that OPFS really does come-across more as a kind-of "local AWS S3" or Azure Blob Storage, which ultimately is still *good enough* for 95% of applications out there... just don't expect to be able to run a high-performance concurrent write-ahead-logged database server in JavaScript on OPFS.

---

#### Comparison of browser-based JavaScript File System APIs:

But don't confuse OPFS with the other filesystem and filesystem-esque APIs:

- MDN has a detailed rundown on [their "File System Access API" page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) (though I feel the page is misnamed, as it covers multiple distinct separate API surfaces, and the way it's written implies some features (like `Window.showOpenFilePicker()`) have wide-support when the reality is quite the opposite.
- Google's [web.dev site also has a rundown of their own](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/).
- Using an `<input type="file">` in HTML with `HTMLInputElement.files` in script allows pages to prompt the user to select a single extant file, or [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-multiple) files (with `<input type="file" multiple>`, or [even an entire directory tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#webkitdirectory) - all of which expose those files to page scripts via the `File` interface.
- Google's [older and now deprecated (but still supported) `chrome.fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/fileSystem/), originally intended for *Chrome Apps* and browser-extensions, webpage scripts may also use it [via `window.requestFileSystem()` or `window.webkitRequestFileSystem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem).
- The [**File and Directory Entries API**](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/), which [has wide browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) for read-only access to the user's local computer filesystem.

  - Note that this API is distinct from, but extends, [the original W3C **File API**](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) which also defines the `File` interface.

    - Also note that both the File API and File and Directory Entries API are largely read-only: so you normally cannot edit, overwrite, delete, or otherwise mutate files nor the underlying filesystem: you can only load/read those files and mutate an in-memory copy of the file, and then explicitly prompt the user to save any changes or new output via `HTMLAnchorElement.download`, [which is about as awkward as it sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server).
    - You *can* create, truncate, edit, and append to existing files [with `createWritable` / `FileSystemWritableFileStream`, but only Chromium-based browsers currently support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/createWritable) (so there's no Firefox or Safari support).
- [The HTML Drag-and-Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) (which concerns use-cases where users drag a file from their desktop, e.g. from Windows File Explorer or macOS Finder and drop it onto some `<div>` in a web-page in a browser window): by listening to the `drag` and `dragover` events scripts can access the dragged data, which may be files, but can also be other types of data).

  - This API functions similarly to `HTMLInputElement.files` in that it doesn't confer any write-access to any files that were dragged-and-dropped by users.

---

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system#browser_compatibility), Firefox now supports OPFS

Answer (score 5):

For storing relatively large data, I'd recommend using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Advantages over local storage:

- Larger size limits
- Supports other data types than string (native typed arrays!)
- Asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) on how much data you can store in local storage. It varies from browser to browser.

If your file size is under the limit, you could copy the file content as a string and save it as a key value pair of "filename":"file content"

Comment: "you could copy the file content as a string" - this is really bad advice when working with binary files sized larger than a few kilobytes. Worst of all: JS's `localStorage` and Base64 encoding functions are synchronous, so you'll block the web-page's/browser's main thread.