# Send image from canvas, and wait for AJAX POST response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am sending the content of a canvas to my API endpoint through ajax, and I would like to be able to wait for the response to come, before proceeding with the next function.
My sending function looks like this:

```
function sendPicture(){
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (width && height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('video', null);

    var reso;
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
        fd.set('video', blob);
    }, 'image/jpeg');

    reso = $.ajax({
      url: "/img",
      type : "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data : fd,
      dataType: "text",
    });

    return reso;
  }
}
```

The function is already working when the ajax statement is used within the `toBlob` callback, but doing so I do not have access anymore to the main scope in order to block the ajax promise.
From the current version of the function I think it would be enough if I managed to extract the `blob` argument outside the callback scope, even though I would have expected that the `fd.set('video', blob)` statement would have already set the formData object from the scope outside where it was initially created.

Does anyone have better suggestions? How can I convert the canvas to the blob without the method with the callback? Or better, how could I fill the formData of the outlying scope?

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear how you get width && height, but it shuld work like this, just create a function outside the callback and call it inside the callback, that way you can access the data from within the callback outside of it

```
     function sendPicture(){
          var video = document.getElementById('video');
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          if (width && height) {
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
        
 
        }
           var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('video', null);
           
         var setBlobOutside = function (blob){
           fd.set('video', blob);
}
            var reso;
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                setBlobOutside(blob);
            }, 'image/jpeg');
        
            reso = $.ajax({
              url: "/img",
              type : "POST",
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              data : fd,
              dataType: "text",
            });
        
            return reso;
          }
        }
```

Your `var fd = new FormData();` is not receving any data, and you are not appending data to it, so it is empty.. you can do it like this `fd.append('key1', 'value1');` or like this , `new FormData([data]);`

here is an example on how to send form data with a file async

```
<form id="formElem">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="John">
  Picture: <input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  formElem.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let response = await fetch('/article/formdata/post/user-avatar', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(formElem)
    });

    let result = await response.json();

    alert(result.message);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: it seems still not to set the form. Could it be that toBlob is asynchronous as well, and I have to explicitly wait for it (even thouhg it return null, and not a promise as far as I understand). For width and height they came originally from a global context, now I moved them to the signature of the sendPicture function.

Comment: PS I also tried to remove the if statement, just to check if this was messing up with scopes in general, since I have seen that you move the respective close parenthesis upwards, but still fd does not get set.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a promise constructor, inspired by [access blob value outside of canvas.ToBlob() async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458849/access-blob-value-outside-of-canvas-toblob-async-function) .
In the following the solution I implemented:

```
function sendPicture(width, height){
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.set('video', blob);

      $.ajax({
        url: "/img",
        type : "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data : fd,
        dataType: "text",
      })
      .done(function(respPost) {
        resolve(respPost)
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    })
  })
}
```

which then is called within html code:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var htmltakebutton = document.getElementById("takebutton");
      htmltakebutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
        var promiseSendPicture = sendPicture(250, 250);

        promiseSendPicture
        .then(function(respPost){
          console.log(respPost);
          updateTakenPhoto();
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
      }, false);
    })()
  </script>
```