# Send plain text form data with AJAX Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to send the content of a form data through AJAX to a python-flask application. Here the basic parts of the Javascript code

```
function sendFormInfo(){
  var formInfo = document.getElementById('formInfo');
  var elems = formInfo.elements;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var getFd = toFormFromElems(elems);

    getFd
    .then(function(fd){

      fd.set('my_key', 'my_value')

      inspectFormData(fd);

      var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

      $.ajax({
        url: "/updategame" + '?_=' + timestamp,
        type : "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "text",
        data : fd
      })
      .done(function(respPost) {
        resolve(respPost)
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        console.log("Post request failed.")
        console.log(data);
      });
      })
    })
}

function inspectFormData(inputFormData){
  for(var pair of inputFormData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ '-> '+ pair[1]); 
 }
}

function toFormFromElems(elems){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var fd = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0, elem; elem = elems[i++];){
      // console.log(elem.id + " -> " + elem.value);
      fd.set(String(elem.id), String(elem.value));
    }

    // console.log(fd);
    resolve(fd);
  })
}
```

and of the python one:

```
@main.route("/updategame", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def update_game():
    print(request.files)
    print(request.files.keys())

    return "success"
```

It seems to me that I can correctly fill the form data:

[image]

but I get an empty dict at the python endpoint:

[image]

while a very very (yes, double very) similar approach has proven to work already, but when sending a video instead ([Send image from canvas, and wait for AJAX POST response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668731/send-image-from-canvas-and-wait-for-ajax-post-response/))

Does anyone have any suggestion? I already tried putting a cache breaker to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send a POST request with form data to flask, it will arrive in [request.form](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form), not request.files, which is for file upload and thus explains, why the video upload works.