# How can I return a value from two asynchronous method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an image compressor without any third-party library.

Here is my code(it will finally returns the blob of compressed image):

```
 async function CompressImage(File, Quality, FileType) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);                        
                canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {                    
                    return blob;
                }, FileType, Quality);            
            }
        }
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(File);
    }
```

It seems there is nothing wrong with my code while always returns an undefined value.

I found out maybe it is the asynchronous problem. The `img.onload` and the `canvas.toBlob` are asynchronous methods.

I think the `promise` may help this while I don't know how to order these methods run one by one and finally returns a value.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access blob value outside of canvas.ToBlob() async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458849/access-blob-value-outside-of-canvas-toblob-async-function)

Comment: @Mellet It is similar while not the same, I have to draw the file to the canvas first and the img.onload is asynchronous  also.

Comment: @MelonNG See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572 for how to wait for the image being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Promise` instead of `async`, in the end is the same but syntactically are not, in a Promise you get 2 functions as parameters (typically called `resolve` and `reject`), these functions can be run inside any callback no problem, but in an `async` function becomes problematic because there's no way to `await` for a function that receives a callback (because is not a Promise that you can `await`).

TLDR;
`async` functions do not play well executing functions that run callbacks, use a Promise directly so you can run `resolve()` anywhere, even if is on a callback function.

For example:

```
function CompressImage(File, Quality, FileType) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image;
  var prom = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    img.onload = function () {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);                        
          canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {                    
              return resolve(blob);
          }, FileType, Quality);            
      }
    }
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(File);
  });
  return prom;
}
```

That should do the trick, look how I'm creating the promise to resolve it with the callback of `canvas.toBlob`, if you notice, the function is not `async` because is returning a Promise directly, but in your code, you can treat it just like an async function.

Another way to do it with a little more updated syntax can be:

```
const CompressImage = async (File, Quality, FileType) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image;
  return await (new Promise(resolve => {
    img.onload = () => {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);                        
            canvas.toBlob(resolve, FileType, Quality);            
        }
    }
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(File);
  }));
};
```

And should be the same.

I haven't tested this but if is broken is pretty close.

UPDATE:

Well, after playing with the jsfiddle you provided I have an interesting finding:

```
$(function () {
    $("#FileUploader").change(function () {
        StartCompress(this.files[0]);
    });
    function StartCompress(input) {
        $("#beforesize").text(input.size);
        CompressFile(input, 0.8).then(blob => $("#afteresize").text(blob.size));
        
    }
    function CompressFile(file, quality) {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var img = new Image();
      var prom = new Promise(resolve => {
        img.onload = () => {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            resolve(blob)
          }, file.type, quality);
        }
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
      return prom;  
    }
});
```

I modified a little bit the code so my ocd can be in peace hahaha, but also, the problem is the MIME (`FileType`), because you are not providing `canvas` with the file type, is just grabbing it and converting it to `png` and that's a lossless format, so it will be bigger if you are selecting a jpg image (that allows loss) and basically scaling it to fit the same size.

Try the code now (I'm using `file.type` to provide the type of the file to `canvas.toBlob`), It goes to hell with `png` and I suppose is related to the issue I pointed out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the code above while met a strange situation: the size of the image will grow a lot no matter what the qualityArgument in canvas.toBlob is.

Comment: @MelonNG can you reproduce the problem on a jsfiddle to try to help you?

Comment: Here is my code in jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/tukspj0y/ . It is so strange that in jsfiddle it even can not get the size of the converted file.

Comment: @MelonNG I edited the response with my findings, hope it helps man.