# create a play/pause button for <img> tag for video streaming

Tags: javascript, video, streaming

I have a `<img>` tag to stream a video by `src="http://ip:8080/video`
and would like to have a play/pause button by javaScript I tried many ways but it does not work.

Note this src just accept img tag to stream the video not accepting video tag.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://192.168.1.130:8080/video" width="500" height="330">
```

Comment: Provide us a demo please

Comment: <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://192.168.1.130:8080/video" width="500" height="330">

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234835/how-to-take-a-photo-of-an-img-video-stream-html5-javascript

Comment: This link for capturing an image I need play/pause buttons in javascript. @Turnip

Comment: That's why I said "_somewhat_ related". And not "This is an exact duplicate". There are concepts in that question that could be used to show a static image when a pause button is clicked. Un-pausing is another problem however.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fix the stop and play button through changing the source of the image.