# Render MJPEG streams in canvas. Specs disallow simply redrawing `canvas` like on `video`

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, mjpeg

I have multiple MJPEG streams - IP Cameras - and I need to display them, animated, to a canvas (I have to do some effects to them etc, so I really need `canvas`).

**OPTION 1**: was using `setInterval`, and redrawing the image to canvas like this: `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,640,360);` but only first frame is drawn to canvas, in Firefox.

According to specs (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3):

> [...] when a CanvasImageSource object represents an animated image in
>   an HTMLOrSVGImageElement, the user agent must use the default image of
>   the animation (the one that the format defines is to be used when
>   animation is not supported or is disabled), or, if there is no such
>   image, the first frame of the animation, when rendering the image for
>   CanvasRenderingContext2D APIs.

So this is not a bug. In Chrome it works at this moment but it is considered a bug and will be "solved" soon...

**OPTION 2**: was using `setInterval` reloading the image (I have the option to get current frame with my ip cameras - so I can get one frame and "refresh" the image) then re-drawing to canvas. That works well but there is a problem that the streams are ~30fps so re-establishing a connection to the server at 1/30 seconds is really hard and I lose a lot of frames (imagine when having multiple cameras on the same page...).

**PS:** I am unable to re-encode MJPEG streams to mp4, webm or other kind of video.

**IDEA:** Is there any option to manually split the mjpeg at boundary, with js and then get each frame? I really don't know how to do this and if it's possible.

**SO:** What can I do?

Thank you very much!

***PS2:*** Jquery or any other free js library accepted. Server-side: only PHP or CGI.

Comment: There is a dupe somewhere, I'll dig a bit to find it... But the only way is by adding a `'?'+Math.random()` at the end of your url in the onload event. This way, the browser will always request it as if it were a new file entirely, thus disregarding the streaming possibility of mjpeg (which means **a lot** of resources to be downloaded too).

Comment: This was marked as duplicate. Can you tell me please where is the first-appeared question and answer? I am unable to find it out. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I may have something new for you to test out. I feel so stupid I didn't thought about this in all these years... but it seems to work on my FF. (I'll edit my answer there though).

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to write it, but you can check again the dupe target. [I made an edit with a third solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144565/3702797), which might better fit your needs: drawing on a new canvas at every frame will actually redraw the current frame entirely.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much!